# best practice for dynamic filtering

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I want to filter with keywords the user can enter.
for example:

models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

now I want to let the user enter "category": "teapot" or "name": "IKEA Glas 0.5L" and the code should in the `get_queryset` method execute:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    VALUE = self.request.GET.keys(SOMEPARAM)
    return Product.objects.filter(SOMEPARAM__contains=VALUE)
```

how can this be done (I know I can do a lot of if clauses, but my model is quite large in terms of fields that can all be handled equally.

so for example for the IKEA example that would be: `Product.objects.filter(name__contains="IKEA Glas ...")`

Comment: I recommend using [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/).